# Generic Error page Angular JS + Spring MVC + Controller Advice

Tags: spring

similar or related question to this post. 
 I have written the multiple  service calls using angular JS. psudo code here

```
 $http.get('name').success(function(response){
          $scope.name= response;
          $log.info($scope.rate);
     }).error(function() {

     });
```

Now I would like to route to single error page let say error.html for any exception occurs

```
how would I route to error.html page in Angular JS instead of touching the hundreds of service calls.

I  know I would have written/route in the error function below , but I DO NOT  want to repeat in reset of my application or hundreds of service calls. 
what is the alternate way. please respond 



   $http.get('indexrates').success(function(response){
              $scope.rates= response;
              $log.info($scope.rates);
         }).error(function() {
              $state.go('error');
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
      public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

      @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
      public ModelAndView
      defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
        // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
        // at the start of this post.
        // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation
                    (e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
          throw e;

        // Otherwise setup and send the user to a default error-view.
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return mav;
      }
    }
```